# I just started learning unity and I can't seem to figure it out, what did I do wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I was following a tutorial on unity and things were going fine but then I got the error 'Assets\PipeSpawnScript.cs(26,18): warning CS8321: The local function 'spawnPipe' is declared but never used' and I can't seem to figure it out what to do, I checked the code and compared it to the code in the tutorial but it was the exact same, here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PipeSpawnScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject pipe;
    public float spawnRate = 2;
    private float timer = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        void spawnPipe();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (timer < spawnRate)
        {
            timer = timer + Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            void spawnPipe();
            timer = 0;
        }
    }

    void spawnPipe()

    {
        Instantiate(pipe, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Here is the link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtQMytORBmM

And I'm using version 2021.3.24f1

It should make a pipe as soon as the player starts the game (Note: I'm recreating Flappy Bird)

Comment: "it was the exact same" https://i.imgur.com/ZhnuqrY.png https://i.imgur.com/HJt1Amx.png

Comment: Welcome to programming! This reminds me sooo much of my first program and the errors it had. For getting started, I'd recommend finding a Discord being run by a friendly Twitch Unity programming streamer. There you can ask lots of basic questions and you'll get lots of friendly support.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I just started programming and its fascinating! I hope I grow to learn much more.

Answer (score 4):

This declares a local function which is never called:

```cs
void Start()
{
    void spawnPipe() {   }
}
```

With `void spawnPipe();` you will get even another error telling you that the local function needs a body.

This calls an existing method:

```cs
void Start()
{
    spawnPipe();
}
```

Remove the `void` keyword!

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't thank you enough for your help